# Ajax request in Laravel returns an empty object

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I'm using `Laravel & jQuery` in order to `insert` data to a `MySQL` table and take back the new id of the new row. The problem is that i get as a response an empty object. I have tried also to `print_r` the result in my Controller but i got back a huge array.

Here is some code.

jQuery :

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "locations/new",
            type: "get", //send it through get method
            data:{name:name,description:description},
            success: function(response) {
              $data = $(response);
              console.log($data);                 
            },
            error: function() {
              console.log("Unable add")
            }
        });
```

Controller :

```
$name= Input::has('name') ? Input::get('name') : null;
        $description= Input::has('description') ? Input::get('description') : null;

        $add = Location::add($name, $description);

        return  $add;
```

and my Model:

```
    public static function add($name,$description){

       $location_id = DB::table('locations')->insertGetId(
        array('name' => $name, 'description' => $description)
        );
        Self::get($location_id);      
    }

    public static function get($location_id){
        $result = DB::table('locations')->where('location_id',$location_id)
                  ->select(DB::raw('location_id,name'));

        $result->get();

        return $result;

    }
```

I know that i might have a mistake here. Please except your answers i would like to know the reason of the mistake.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: try `console.log(response);` see what happen

Comment: i get (an empty string)

Comment: Just throwing in the air, maybe i'm wrong, but shouldn't it be `return Self::get($location_id);`?

Comment: @OfirBaruch I have tried it and i get "could
 not be converted to string" error

Comment: That's weird. Let's try and break this code in order to debug it. Undo my suggestion and add `var_dump($result)` before `return $result`. What's the output?

Comment: i get back a Huge object. Just a small piece of it `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder)#248 (27) {
  ["connection":protected]=>
  object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection)#240 (17) {
    ["pdo":protected]=>
    object(PDO)#241 (0) {
    }
    ["readPdo":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["reconnector":protected]=> `

Comment: I don't like the `syntax error` part hhh. Can you please share the whole output in your question (use `Code` tag)

Comment: @OfirBaruch Unfortunately not, the output is really huge, in order to reach the end i have to scroll about 2 minutes, it looks like its exporting all laravel classes in some way...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77570/discussion-between-ofir-baruch-and-maks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After co-investigating (@chat), the problem seemed to be in the Query builder.

After adding `var_dump($result)` the output was:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder)#248 (27) { ["connection":prot
```

I suggested removing the `DB::raw` function as you can pass fields to the `select` function, and from convenient reasons to attach the ->get() function to the same line. So the final query builder code would be:

```
$result = DB::table('locations')->where('location_id',$location_id)->select('location_id',‌​'name')->get();
```

Which solved the problem.

**Update - The Reason**

After looking deeper in the source of the framework, I've found out that:

```
/**
 * Set the columns to be selected.
 *
 * @param  array  $columns
 * @return $this
 */
public function select($columns = array('*'))
{
    $this->columns = is_array($columns) ? $columns : func_get_args();
    return $this;
}
```

So the `select` function is expecting an array or arguments as `columns`, and when `db::raw` was in use - it returned a string which conflicted with the expected parameters of the `select` function.

Comment: It might work, but you are reinventing the wheel. Please check out my answer and see if it works. It is much cleaner and is done "the laravel way".

Answer (score 0):

This is what your controller should look like

```
$location = new Location();
$location->name = Input::get('name', null);
$location->description= Input::get('description', null);
$location->save();
return response()->json(location);
```

Comment: It works only if i change to this `return $location;` But how can i get the inserted id of the new row?

Comment: I made a mistake. `return response()->json($location);` should also work well, you might be expecting different output tho. Anyway I think this is much cleaner and easier to understand. Laravel is beautiful and native methods should be utilized. It could be even further optimized depending on what you model and fillable property looks like. Read the documentation. Its your friend!